# Non-documented API & headers

Tags: c++, objective-c, header, webkit, javascriptcore

I'm using JavaScriptCore in one of my Objective-C project, and I'd like to know at any time what's the current file & line when falling into a JS callback.

There is no way to do it with the [public headers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/WebKit_JavaScriptCore_Ref/_index.html), so I took a look at the [sources](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/tree/master/Source/JavaScriptCore) and it seems possible to access the file & line by using some C++ code.

```
// ctx is a JSContextRef, that's the only type I have an access to
JSC::JSValue jsCtx = toJS(ctx);
CodeBlock* codeBlock = jsCtx->codeBlock();

// Line
unsigned sourceOffset = codeBlock->sourceOffset();

// Source URL
SourceProvider* sourceProvider = codeBlock->source();
const String& url = sourceProvider->url();
```

It obviously requires the definitions of `JSC`, `JSValue`, `CodeBlock`, and `SourceProvider`. I have all these in separate headers, but it's really massive.

- Should I directly include those headers?
- What if those files require other headers? I might end by having multiple headers that I won't use.
- Let's forget that the internal source code might change: is what I want to do even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can know this information from the public Headers itself. Here you go:

When the exception occurs, the exception object contains the following keys:

line, sourceId, sourceURL, name, message

You can access the values for these keys to find in which file (sourceURL) and in which line number (line) the exception has occurred.

Example:

```
JSObjectRef exceptionObj = JSValueToObject(context, exception, NULL);

//Convert the exceptionObj into dictionary (I leave the implementation of this to you..)
NSDictionary *exceptionDict = [self convertJSObjectToDictionary:exceptionObj];

NSString *lineNumber = [exceptionDict objectForKey:@"line"];
NSString *fileName = [exceptionDict objectForKey:@"sourceURL"];

NSLog(@"Exception has occurred in file:%@ at line number:%@", fileName, lineNumber);
```

Hope this helps!

~ Sunil Phani Manne

Comment: Thanks Sunil but I want to get a stack trace at any time, not only after an exception. So when a native C function is bound into the JS context and that this function is called, I want to know what called it and when.